# Add link to call by Skype in a message - relative reference

Tags: rules, users

I have rules' module and in the last part I set an action to show a message. In that message I want to add a link to call one user by Skype, I am using this:

```
     $message = "<a href='skype:echo123?call'>Click to call to your student</a>";

     echo $message;
```

That only works in php (You can try it http://phptester.net/).

But the problem is that Drupal is using that reference as a relative url so when I click it, it takes me to "http://www.example.com/yyyy/echo123?call". How can I do to do a reference to Skype?.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your link contains "skype" protocol that is filtered out by filter_xss_bad_protocol() Drupal core function.
You can install [Filter Protocols](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_protocols) module which allows you to configure allowed protocols. Skype protocol is not included in configuration by default, you'll have to add it yourself - then your skype link will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I didn't know that  :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about the skype stuff so this might not be ideal but can't you use:
    $message = "Click to call to your student";

That should still open up in skype if you've got it as the default. Also means people without skype e.g. mobile phone users can click it directly and make a call via their phone